# How to use a private static method for sorting queues with quicksort

Tags: java, quicksort

This quick sort must use a queue. Method signatures cannot be altered and no new methods are allowed. They want me to use the private partition method but it's static void and there are no class fields so I have no idea how that would actually help the quick sort algorithm.

My attempt which just returns an empty queue, which makes sense, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Queue;

public class QuickSort {

    /**
     * Returns a new queue that contains the given queues catenated together.
     * <p>
     * The items in q2 will be catenated after all of the items in q1.
     *
     * @param q1 A Queue of items
     * @param q2 A Queue of items
     * @return A Queue containing the items of
     * q1 followed by the items of q2.
     */
    private static <Item extends Comparable> Queue<Item> catenate(Queue<Item> q1, Queue<Item> q2) {
        Queue<Item> catenated = new Queue<Item>();
        for (Item item : q1) {
            catenated.enqueue(item);
        }
        for (Item item : q2) {
            catenated.enqueue(item);
        }
        return catenated;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random item from the given queue.
     *
     * @param items A Queue of items
     * @return A random item from items
     */
    private static <Item extends Comparable> Item getRandomItem(Queue<Item> items) {
        int pivotIndex = (int) (Math.random() * items.size());
        Item pivot = null;
        // Walk through the queue to find the item at the given index.
        for (Item item : items) {
            if (pivotIndex == 0) {
                pivot = item;
                break;
            }
            pivotIndex--;
        }
        return pivot;
    }

    /**
     * Partitions the given unsorted queue by pivoting on the given item.
     *
     * @param unsorted A Queue of unsorted items
     * @param pivot    The item to pivot on
     * @param less     An empty Queue. When the function completes, this queue will contain
     *                 all of the items in unsorted that are less than the given pivot.
     * @param equal    An empty Queue. When the function completes, this queue will contain
     *                 all of the items in unsorted that are equal to the given pivot.
     * @param greater  An empty Queue. When the function completes, this queue will contain
     *                 all of the items in unsorted that are greater than the given pivot.
     */
    private static <Item extends Comparable> void partition(
            Queue<Item> unsorted, Item pivot,
            Queue<Item> less, Queue<Item> equal, Queue<Item> greater) {
        Queue<Item> out = unsorted;

        while(!unsorted.isEmpty()){
            Item t = out.dequeue();
            if (t.compareTo(pivot) > 0){
                greater.enqueue(t);
            }else if(t.compareTo(pivot) == 0){
                equal.enqueue(t);
            }else less.enqueue(t);
        }
        quickSort(less);
        quickSort(greater);
       out = catenate(catenate(less,equal), greater);
    }





    /**
     * Returns a Queue that contains the given items sorted from least to greatest.
     *
     * @param items  A Queue of possibly unsorted items
     * @return       A Queue of sorted items
     */
    public static <Item extends Comparable> Queue<Item> quickSort(
            Queue<Item> items) {
        if (items.size() <= 1){
            return items;
        }
       Item ran = getRandomItem(items);
        Queue<Item> less = new Queue<>();
        Queue<Item> more = new Queue<>();
        Queue<Item> equal = new Queue<>();
        partition(items, ran, less, equal, more);
        return items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Queue<Integer> non = new Queue<>();
        non.enqueue(108);
        non.enqueue(180);
        non.enqueue(10);
        non.enqueue(810);

        non = quickSort(non);
        System.out.println(non.toString());
    }
}
```

This outputs an empty list.

Comment: The result is probably in `out` which you are not returning from `partition`.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: If you can't change the signature of `partition` (which seems odd) you'd need to reuse one of the passed queues to return the results. From the rest of your code it seems as if the `unsorted` (or `out` due to `out = unsorted`) queue should be used for that - in that case instead of `out = catenate(catenate(less,equal), greater);` try `out.addAll(...);` (due to the while loop that queue should be empty at that stage).

Comment: Yes I don't know how to get the variable out into the global frame. The method signatures aren't supposed to be altered, but its a private static method with no fields. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks guys I had to take a closer look at what is point to what. Forgot catenate creates a new object